# Java Array de String Multidimensional

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un ejercicio en el estoy utilizando JTree, para rellenar los subnodos y las hojas utilizo un Array 2D irregular (Jagger), cuando implemento los ciclos for anidados para recorrerlos me ocurre algo que no encuentro como resolver, se me desplazan las hojas de sus nodos, he buscado y no se si el problema es en el segundo for del ciclo y no sé como resolverlo, les pongo mi código:

```
    DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Mundo");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode pais = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("España");
    rootNode.add(pais);
    DefaultMutableTreeNode community = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Comunidades Atónomas");
    pais.add(community);
    String[][] comunid = {{"Comunidad de Madrid", "Andalucia", "Aragón", "Principado de Asturias",
                        "Islas Baleares", "Islas Canarias", "Cantabria", "Castilla-La Mancha",
                        "Castilla y León", "Cataluña", "Comunidad Valenciana", "Extremadura",
                        "Galicia", "La Rioja", "Región de Murcia", "Comunidad Floral de Navarra",
                        "País Vasco"}, {"Madrid"}, {"Almería", "Cádiz", "Córdoba", "Granada", 
                        "Huelva", "Jaén", "Málaga", "Sevilla"}, {"Huesca", "Teruel", "Zaragoza"}, 
                        {"Asturias"}, {"Baleares"}, {"Las Palmas", "Santa Cruz de Tenerife"}, 
                        {"Cantabria"}, {"Albacete", "Ciudad Real", "Cuenca", "Guadalajara", "Toledo"}, 
                        {"Ávila", "Burgos", "León", "Palencia", "Salamanca", "Segovia", "Soria", 
                        "Valladolid", "Zamora"}, {"Barcelona", "Gerona", "Lérida", "Tarragona"}, 
                        {"Alicante", "Castellón", "Valencia"}, {"Badajoz", "Cáceres"}, {"La Coruña", 
                        "Lugo", "Orense", "Pontevedra"}, {"La Rioja"}, {"Región de Murcia"}, {"Navarra"}
                        , {"Álava", "Guipúzcoa", "Vizcaya"}};
    //System.out.println(comunid[2][0]);
    for (int i=0; i<comunid[0].length; i++) {
        String TxtEnComm = comunid[0][i];
        DefaultMutableTreeNode Comm = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(TxtEnComm);
        community.add(Comm);
        for (int j=0; j<comunid[i].length; j++) {
            String TxtEnProv = comunid[i][j];
            DefaultMutableTreeNode Prov = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(TxtEnProv);
            Comm.add(Prov);
        }
    }
```

El problema creo que es en for (j=0; j<comunid[i].length; j++), (yo soy nuevo en esto) cuando entra por primera vez i==0 y me vuelve a poner los valores de la primera dimension dentro de la dimension [0]. Adjunto Imagen del resultado:
[image: El JTree con las Hojas corridas]

Ya no tengo enlaces neuronales que me respondan, les agradecería que me pudieran ayudar

Comment: Ya he utilizado condicionales para cuando i=0 y j=0,buscando controlar el acceso al segundo for y no he podido encontrar una solución, no encuentro como, una ayudita por favor

Answer (score 0):

A ver, la solución que encontré no sé si será la mas profesional (no me lo parece, pero WYSIWYG), el problema es que como tanto las Comunidades Autónomas y las provincias son dimensiones del mismo array, cuando entraba a evaluar `for (j=0; j<comunid[i].length; j++)`
con la llamada a `comunid[i][j]`, cuando ambos (i y j) eran =0, me agregaba todas las comunidades en la Comunidad de Madrid, donde solo debía existir "Madrid", la solución fue:

- Antes del segundo ciclo `for`, incrementar i `++i;`.
- Después del cierre del segundo `for` decrementar i `--i;`
  De ese modo cuando entraba al segundo ciclo, el valor de i = +1 y al salir le quitaba 1 para que volviera a seguir su conteo normal del primer ciclo.
  De esa forma me funcionó